# Symfony 3.0.4 security.secure_random doesn't exists

Tags: symfony

I'm migrating symfony 2.6 app to the 3.0.4, I'm in a trouble with `security.secure_random` service, I was using it with dependency injection. Which is representing in [security.xml](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/security.xml)

but I cannot see in 3.0.x I checked changelog every pixel of the project where it does go ? That I'm missing something ?

Comment: `SecureRandom` was deprecated some time ago (v2.8), [see here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15879).

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi I see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class deprecated in 2.8 and removed in 3.0 in favour of the `random_bytes` function.

Essentialy the `SecureRandomInterface` had one `nextBytes` method, which behaves exactly as the PHP7 [random_bytes](http://php.net/manual/de/function.random-bytes.php) function.

You can install https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat for forward compatibility